# missing file - wouldnt load- i just want linux

Tags: software-installation

I am downloading Ubuntu through the website. I am downloading Ubuntu 12.04 LTS desktop. I already downloaded it once and rebooted my computer but when I tried loading it I got the message that there were missing files and Ubuntu wont work. I downloaded the file in Firefox and opened it with cyber link IOS viewer. I honestly have no idea what I'm doing, I just want Linux along side my windows! please help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a procedure from ubuntu to install it using the windows installer. **Not for Win 8**

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows

Comment: It seems that i have left that important info out, I am currently running windows 8. is there a way to do that with windows 8? the link you gave me showed every step that i did but when i go to the last step it said there was a missing file and was unable to load, then redirecting me to the os selection again